# Parse wolframalpha to latex

Tags: wolframalpha

I'm using wolframalpha api to display the step-by-step solutions. The api returns each step in a plaintext form with the mathematical expression is not in Latex; therefore, it's really hard for me to render the view. Anyone know how to parse the WolframAlpha result to latex or anything that can be easily render on the web?

Comment: you mean the [TeXForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) function?

Comment: yes, but i use directly from web api instead of using Wolfram mathematica. Could you show me how to do it?